# creating video for android streaming

Tags: android, streaming, http-streaming

This is answer for my search which i did for creating videos to stream on android.
Though android supports mp4 for streaming but not easily.
The simple steps which i deduced from my experience are:-
1) using super encoder first of all encode the videos the parameters are-

A) Top parameters:

a) mp4 as container
   b) mpeg-4 video codec
   c) aac-lc audio codec

B) Video parameters:

d) dimension as 380x480,the aspect ratio will be automatically created
   e) frame rate automatically sets as 29.97 or else give that parameter
   f) bitrate as 480 kbps
   g) uncheck high quality ,top quality, crop,padding in the options column

C) Audio parameters:

h) sampling frequency as 44100
   i) channels as 2
   j) bitrate as 96kbps
   k) detect all streams as checked

D) Set the output path to a different path from the source example if video you are encoding from is in d:\ then set the output path other than d:\ like d:\encoded and keep a watch on it,for some videos i was stuck in the middle so i closed super and got them in that folder till it has encoded.the output path is set from output managment by right clicking on super

Now after encoding u just need to hint the videos for that i used MP4Box on linux since i m linux addict.
the simple command on linux is MP4Box -hint myvideofile.mp4

This videos could be easily streamed from a web server also using http protocol or can be used on darwin server too.

Hope this would help others